# Retrieving attachment names and downloading the attachments

Tags: c#, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, email-attachments

hoping someone here can enlighten me on how to use Microsoft Graph to download attachments from emails. I am trying to automate the download and processing of attachments from Office 365 mail with certain subject. So far I have managed to iterate the messages and put them in a list called messageList, but have not been successful in retrieving the names of the attachment in each messages and also to download them. Here are my code :

```
     var messages = await graphClient
             .Users[userEmail]
             .MailFolders[folderId]
             .Messages
             .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
             {
                 //requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
                 //requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
                 requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = 
                 "receivedDateTime ge 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z and (from/emailAddress/address) eq 'donotreply@sinarmasland.com'";
                 requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "receivedDateTime desc"};
             });
var messageList = new List<Message>();
     var pageIterator = PageIterator<Message, MessageCollectionResponse>.
         CreatePageIterator(graphClient, messages, (message) =>
     {
         
         //Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
         messageList.Add(message);
         return true;
     });
     await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
     while (pageIterator.State != PagingState.Complete)
     {
         await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
     }
     foreach (var m in messageList)
     {
         if (m.HasAttachments == true)
         {
             var attachments=m.Attachments;
             if (attachments != null)
             {
                 foreach (var attachment in attachments)
                 {
    
                     Console.WriteLine("Attachment Name : " + attachment.Name);
                 }
             }
             Console.WriteLine(m.Subject + " Has attachment(s)");
         }
    
     }
```

If I view the m object in Autos, it's properties for Attachment is null.
[image]
Please help, especially in downloading the files. thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Could you please provide more code? At least how do you create messages property or the request you send to read messages

Comment: @user2250152, I've edited my question to add what you've requested.

Comment: You are looping over a mesagelist (`foreach (var m in messageList)`). I think you should loop over a message to get all attachments?

Comment: @Luuk what is there to loop if I choose to loop over a message? each message attachments object is null, while it shouldn't be null because it has attachments and I made sure to retrieve only messages with attachment

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are not included by default, you need to use expand to tell the server that attachments should be included in the response. Then you need to cast each attachment to `FileAttachment` to be able to read data

```
var messages = await graphClient
 .Users[""]
 .MailFolders[""]
 .Messages
 .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
 {
     requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter =
     "receivedDateTime ge 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z and (from/emailAddress/address) eq 'donotreply@sinarmasland.com'";
     requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "receivedDateTime desc" };
     // return also attachments
     requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "attachments" };
 });
var messageList = new List<Message>();
var pageIterator = PageIterator<Message, MessageCollectionResponse>.
    CreatePageIterator(graphClient, messages, (message) =>
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
        messageList.Add(message);
        return true;
    });
await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
while (pageIterator.State != PagingState.Complete)
{
    await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
}
foreach (var m in messageList)
{
    if (m.HasAttachments == true)
    {
        foreach (var attachment in m.Attachments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attachment Name : " + attachment.Name);
            if (attachment is FileAttachment fileAttachment)
            {
                // content is base64 encoded bytes
                var base64String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileAttachment.ContentBytes);
                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
                File.WriteAllBytes("path", bytes);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(m.Subject + " Has attachment(s)");
}
```

From performance point of view, it can be better to filter messages with attachments

```
var messages = await graphClient
 .Users[""]
 .MailFolders[""]
 .Messages
 .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
 {
     requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter =
     "receivedDateTime ge 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z and (from/emailAddress/address) eq 'donotreply@sinarmasland.com' and hasAttachments eq true";
     requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Orderby = new string[] { "receivedDateTime desc" };
 });
```

and for each message make a separate call to return attachments

```
var attachments = await graphClient
 .Users[""]
 .MailFolders[""]
 .Messages["{message_id}"].Attachments.GetAsync()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot martin, you rock. Man, Microsoft really is different,lol. I would check the query parameters next time I use Microsoft API again